# Is it possible to limit the data to a number and left data combine to **Others** in GoodDataUI visualizations?

Tags: reactjs, gooddata

Is it possible to limit the data to a number and left data combine to **Others** in GoodDataUI visualizations (specially charts) as like in below snapshot?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

GoodData is currently working on a Ranking Filter functionality that will enable you to limit the number of TOP or BOTTOM results in insights out of the box. It should be released in November 2020, here's a screenshot of work in progress:

[image: Ranking Filter]

However, to achieve the **"Other group" behavior** you are describing using [GD.UI](https://sdk.gooddata.com/gooddata-ui/), I would proceed by implementing a custom visualization using the [`<Execute />`](https://sdk.gooddata.com/gooddata-ui/docs/execute_component.html) component, and modifying the execution result on the client to achieve the expected behavior.

> For more detailed howto, please feel free to ask our [GoodData Community](https://community.gooddata.com/).

*Disclaimer: I worked at GoodData when answering this.*

Comment: Thanks @Bugs Bunny for reply. I am also implementing a custom visualization usig <Execute/>